# How to get the total price with id_cart with SQL QUERY

Tags: mysql

I have two table:

ps_cart_product:

```
+---------+------------+------------
| id_cart | id_product | quantity  | 
+---------+------------+------------
|  10454  |    828     |     2     |
+---------+------------+------------
```

ps_product:

```
+---------+----------------
| id_product |    price   | 
+------------+------------+
|     828    |  50.000000 |
+------------+------------+
```

And I would like to get the total price from id_cart = 10454 with a query.

This query below works but does not take into consideration the column quantity:

```
SELECT SUM(price) 
  FROM ps_product 
 WHERE id_product IN (SELECT id_product FROM ps_cart_product WHERE id_cart = 10454;
```

Does anyone know how to add the column quantity in this query ?

Thank you very much for your help,

Cyril

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform a LEFT INNER JOIN on both tables instead of a subquery

```sql
SELECT 
  SUM(ps_product.price * ps_cart_product.quantity) 
FROM ps_product 
  JOIN ps_cart_product 
    ON ps_product.id_product = ps_cart_product.id_product 
WHERE 
    ps_cart_product.id_cart = 10454;
```

Comment: Hello Oluwafemi Sule and a Thank you very much for your quick solution it works like a charm ;)